# How do I specify the Help Link, Support Link and Update Information?

Tags: hyperlink, wix, metadata, addremoveprograms

I've authored a few Wix installers but I've noticed that my products, when installed and viewed in Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, are a little light on metadata compared to some other installs. Many installed products contain items such as:

- Help Link (URL)
- Support Link (URL)
- Update Information (URL).

These items show up at the bottom of the control panel when the installed product is selected. My products, installed with Wix, don't have these items, they just have a version number. I can't see anywhere obvious in Wix where I can add these items, searching the Wix help file produces no matches for any of these items.

Does anyone know if this is possible in Wix? I'm sure it must be...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's a bunch of Windows Installer properties to take over this. They all start with ARP (Add Remove Programs). Take a look at [the full list with description of each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368032.aspx). In WiX this will look like any other property set:

```
<Property Id="ARPHELPLINK" Value="http://support.mycompany.com" />
```